# setting and getiing html tag values with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have list of objects called "tables", two input fields for creating an object and increase or decreasing the number of objects and a html "h5" tag that shows the total number of the objects. I want to show "creatinTables" input field when the total number of tables equals zero. And if user creates a table I want to hide creatingTables field and show UpdateTables(increase or decrease the number) field.

I can get the total numbers from databse and send to the totalTableNumber field correctly but I could not run the jquery codes properly that for showing and hiding the fields.

> HTML

```
<div class="container">

  <!-- CREATE TABLES -->
  <div id="CreateTables" class="input-group mb-3">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon3">Enter the Number of Tables</span>
    </div>
    <form [formGroup]="tableForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="submitTableNumber()">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-5">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="counter" id="basic" aria-describedby="basic-addon3">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-5">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark">Save</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <!-- INCREASE-DECREASE NUMBER OF TABLES -->
  <div id="UpdateTables" class="input-group mb-3">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <span class="input-group-text" >UPDATE THE NUMBER OF TABLES</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-9" style="margin-left: 3%;">
      <form [formGroup]="tableForm">
        <div>
          <label>Increase the tables</label><span></span>
          <button type="button" (click)="addTable()" class="btn btn-sm btn-dark">+</button>
        </div>
      </form>
      <form [formGroup]="tableForm">
        <div>
          <label>Decrease the tables</label><span></span>
          <button type="button" (click)="removeTable()" class="btn btn-sm btn-dark">-</button>
        </div>
      </form>

    </div>

  </div>
  <!-- TOTAL TABLE NUMBER -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <h5>Total Table NUmber</h5>
    </div>
    <div id="totalTableNumber" class="col-lg-6">
      <h5 ></h5>
    </div>
  </div>
```

> Codes that I get the data from DB and send HTML

```
displayTables() {
    this.companyService.getTables().subscribe(data => {
      this.tables = data;
      this.tableNumber = data.length;

      jQuery('#totalTableNumber').text(this.tableNumber);
      console.log('Total Table Number :' + this.tableNumber);
    });
  }
```

> Jquery to Show/Hide fields

```
 formsVisibility() {

    const displayedNumber = $('#totalTableNumber').text();
    console.log('displayed: ' + displayedNumber);

    if (parseInt(displayedNumber, 10) > 0) {
      $('#CreateTables').hide();
      $('#UpdateTables').show();

    } else {
      $('#CreateTables').show();
      $('#UpdateTables').hide();

    }
  }
```

> Output

*It is displaying the total number of tables correctly (over zero) but createTables field is not hidden and update field is now shown. And console log for displayed is empty, nothing is shown.*

Comment: What are you doing here angular or jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the execution order. After i arranged it, then the codes worked properly